# QWebView save to HTML with local image

Tags: html, qt, pyqt, pdf-generation

I am doing something like this:

```
        doc = QWebView()
        printer = QPrinter()
        printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
        printer.setOutputFileName(filename)
        doc.setHtml('''    
...
<img src="star.jpg" />
...
''',QUrl.fromLocalFile("/var/www/icons/")
)
        doc.print_(printer)
```

I get a nicely printed PDF...without the image. Most of the advice I have seen is to use the baseurl parameter, which I have done, and I have tried just about every combination of urls in the src/Qurl values.

Is there any way to get QWebView to print out  images to a PDF?

Comment: Are you sure this is a conversion-to-pdf problem? Is the image visible in QWebView? Does it show if the document is sent directly to printer?

Comment: @AlexVhr ...not sure at all. The only way I have to visualize is via printing to the PDF...is there another way to see it? Maybe I can make QWebView bring up a window or something (although I am currently running it as a CGI python script using Xvfb for graphics).

Comment: Of cause there is, but for that you will need a minimal QApplication set up. I will elaborate more, but not in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, lets try to make sure that the image is visible in QWebView at all and you indeed have a problem with PDF conversion. So you need to run this and see if it works:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWebKit

class MyWin(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())
        self.view = QtWebKit.QWebView(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.view)
        self.view.setHtml('''
...
<img src="star.jpg" />
...
''', QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile("/var/www/icons/")
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWin()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: yes I tested this and it works fine, the image pops up in a window. Still no luck with the PDF export...even using the same html.